# Using rubzip2 and paperclip in rails, how to you create a temporary zip file and save it to paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, paperclip, mime-types

I had some code preciously that zipped up a load of files, it created a zip file in the tmp file system and added files to it there.

I'm trying to make it more efficient by using ruby's Tempfile to store the file in the code instead of manually writing it to the tmp directory myself and deleting it later on.

I've written this code to try and do it…

```
def zip_up_files
  require 'zip/zip'

  t = Tempfile.new(["temp-filename-#{export_type}", '.zip'], :type => 'application/zip')
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |z|
    #pop some files in the zip...
  end

  #save it to the has_attachment :download on the model
  self.download = File.open(t.path)
  self.save

  #delete TempFile...
  t.close
end
```

This sucsfullt saved the Tempfile to the .download on the model. However if you now navigate to the saved zip file it's not a zip file but a garbled text document. I was wondering if there's something missing the creation or the saving of the zip before it get's saved to modle. I've tried putting the type into the TempFile creating. It looks like the zip's missing a MimeType. But I'm not sure, can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you've written a binary file to disk, but then you open it in text mode rather than binary mode. This will definitely mess up the data.

```
# Opens in text mode by default!
#self.download = File.open(t.path)

# Change to...
self.download = File.open(t.path, 'rb')
```

Incidentally, `close` does not delete the temp file. The file is getting deleted when the file handle is garbage collected. It's recommended to call `unlink` explicitly to delete the temp file, otherwise you'll have tons of temp files on disk waiting to be garbage collected. (See the [synopsis and good practices in the TempFile docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html).)

```
#delete TempFile...
t.close
t.unlink
```

Answer (score 1):

i think file name is not generated right

```
t = Tempfile.new(["temp-filename-#{export_type}", '.zip'], :type => 'application/zip')
```

after this line you can do

```
   p t.path
```

and check it the printed value in the terminal

## or

you can update you code to match this it words fine with me

```
    require 'zip/zip'
    Zip::ZipFile.open("my.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
     |zipfile|
      #do some awesome staff
     }
```